# How to create a pool of threads

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, python-multithreading

I am trying to scrape all the products on this site:
https://www.jny.com/collections/jackets

It will get links to all the products and then scrape them one by one. I am trying to speed up this process by multi-threading. Here is the code:

```
def yield1(self, url):
    print("inside function")
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)


def parse(self, response):
    print("in herre")
    self.product_url =  response.xpath('//div[@class = "collection-grid js-filter-grid"]//a/@href').getall()
    print(self.product_url)
    for pu in self.product_url:
        print("inside the loop")
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
             print("inside thread")
             executor.map(self.yield1, response.urljoin(pu))
```

It is supposed to create a pool of 10 threads each of which will execute yield1() on the list of URLs. Problem is that yield1() method is not being called.

Comment: Are you using asyncio or concurrent.futures?

Comment: concurrent.futures

Comment: Shouldn't you be capturing the futures and iterating over them when they're done? https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

Comment: giving this error: object of type Request has no len

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yield1` is a generator function. To get it to yield a value you have to *call next* on it.
Change it so it returns a value

```
def yield1(self, url):
    print("inside function")
    return scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)
```

---

caveat:I don't really know anything about Scrapy.

The [Overview in the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html) says that requests are made asynchronously. Your code doesn't look like the examples given in those docs. The example in the overview shows subsequent requests being made in the `parse` method using `response.follow`.  Your code looks like you are trying to extract links from a page and then asynchronously scrape those links and parse them with a different method. Since it seems like Scrapy will do this for you and handle the asynchronicity (?)  I think you just need to define another parse method in your spider and use `response.follow` to schedule more asynchronous requests. You shouldn't need concurrent.futures, [the new requests should all be processed asynchrounously](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#topics-architecture).

I have no way of testing this but I think your spider should look more like this:

```
class TempSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'foo'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.jny.com/collections/jackets',
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        self.product_url =  response.xpath('//div[@class = "collection-grid js-filter-grid"]//a/@href').getall()
        for pu in self.product_url:
            print("inside the loop")
            response.urljoin(pu)
            yield response.follow(response.urljoin(pu), self.parse_product)

    def parse_product(self, response):
        '''parses the product urls'''
```

This assumes `self.product_url =  response.xpath('//div[@class = "collection-grid js-filter-grid"]//a/@href').getall()` does what it is supposed to.

Maybe even a separate Spider to parse the subsequent links. Or use a [CrawlSpider](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) .

---

Relevant SO Q&A's
[Scraping links with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49694649/scraping-links-with-scrapy)
[scraping web page containing anchor tag  using scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988246/scraping-web-page-containing-anchor-tag-a-href-using-scrapy)
[Use scrapy to get list of urls, and then scrape content inside those urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44913798/use-scrapy-to-get-list-of-urls-and-then-scrape-content-inside-those-urls) (looks familiar)
[Scrapy, scrape pages from second set of links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43493659/scrapy-scrape-pages-from-second-set-of-links)
[many more](https://www.google.com/search?q=scrapy%20extract%20links%20from%20a%20page%20and%20scrape%20them%20site:stackoverflow.com&newwindow=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX1deznorkAhWjIzQIHXwWAAUQrQIoBDAJegQICRAM&biw=1680&bih=945)

Comment: It seems to be working but now it isn't calling callback function parse_product

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Did this answer your question?

Comment: How do you know the callback isn't being called?

Comment: Code exits without executing even a single statement within parse_product